# How to call function after two click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created two datepicker inputs for from date and to date.

For example:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control" id="fromDate">
<input class="datepicker form-control" id="toDate">
```

And datepicker:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-front">
...
</div>
```

After the user clicks on `#toDate` and clicks on `#ui-datepicker-div` I'd like to call this function:

```
$('.icon-disable-date').hide();
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$('#toDate').on('click', function () {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', function () {
        $('.icon-disable-date').hide();
    });
});
```

But this code does not work for me.

Comment: What you actually want is when both inputs have a value, hide the div.

Comment: Hi @KevinB ,  I need after click on the #ui-datepicker-div for #toDate call this function. `$('.icon-disable-date').hide();`

Comment: I think you don't know what you need.

Comment: @KevinB , Excuse me, My speak english is not good. I need call function after select date in `id="toDate"` .

Comment: I think @KevinB is asking why you want to do this.  It seems like you want the icon to disappear after both dates have been selected, but the way you are going about it is over-complicated and narrowly defined.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to apply a change event to both inputs that monitors the value of both inputs, so that on change, if both the inputs have a value, hide said icon. No weird click events needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed by @KevinB in the comments, if you want the icon to disappear when both dates are selected, you can do this much easier using a change event on the input:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('.datepicker').change(function() {
    if ($('#fromDate').val() != "" && $('#toDate').val() != "") {
        $('.icon-disable-date').hide();
    }
});
```

This works regardless of order and even if the user types a date instead of selecting one.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tycugh4t/

You can also do this with a datepicker `onChange` event, but it will not catch cases where the user types in the input fields:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    if ($('#fromDate').val() != "" && $('#toDate').val() != "") {
      $('.icon-disable-date').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for help me. Your code in JSFiddle is correct but this code in my project in not work !!! why?

Comment: I remove `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` :-) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting HTML5 supported browsers, this can be done with Promises. Or you can add Promises Polyfill for browsers not supported.

```
  var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      $('#toDate').on('click', function () {   
           resolve(true)
      })
  }).then(function(result){
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       if(result) {
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').onSelect(function(){
            resolve(true)
          })
       }else {
         reject();
       }
    })
  }).then(function(result){
     if(result){
        $('.icon-disable-date').hide();
     }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me, This code is very good but after select date, this code `$('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', function () {` not work!!! this code just work for click on the `#ui-datepicker-div`! don't work for select date !!!!

Comment: I need call function after select date in id="toDate"

Comment: Thank you, But `$('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', function () {` not wotk after select date !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! this code work for click without select date !!!!!! :-(

Comment: ok, datepicker's date function is not `click` event. Updating the code. sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: :-((((((( `$('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', function () {` not work for click and select date :-(